# Wrap image in fixed height and width

Tags: html, css

I have few boxes with texts blocks including logo images. Logo images come from back end. My client needs to wrap those images in fixed width and height. So the boxes look uniform and good for consistency.

**Problem**

Images sizes are diffrent. Some logos have higher width, less height like that. So I can't wrap logos into my fixed height, width box. It looks very messy.

[image]

**My solution**

I have given max width and max height to logo image. Then it automatically adjust and show without damaging aspect ratio. But most cases, show white spaces in left and right. I think it's normal.

[image]

Or do I need to use photoshop, make logo to my fixed height, width and upload? Or any other solution available for achieving this kind of situation?

**My code**

```css
.img-wrap-quotes{
 text-align:center;
}
        
.img-wrap-quotes img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 70px;
 max-width: 226px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap-quotes">
 <img class="img-responsive " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1c/LegalAndGeneral_Logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: set only static height or static width, so that other part will calculated automatically.

Comment: You mean max-width and max-height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the size of logo container and keep the transparent logo just in middle of container with fixed max-height.

```css
.img-wrap-quotes{
 max-height: 70px;
 max-width: 226px;
 width:226px;
 height:70px;
 background:#0000ff;
 text-align:center;
}
        
.img-wrap-quotes img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 70px;
 max-width: 226px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap-quotes">
 <img class="img-responsive " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1c/LegalAndGeneral_Logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Then what about the logo with background image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `object-fit: cover`? Apply that property to your `img`, so you can set the `height` and `width` of the container, and the `img` will retain its aspect ratio.

```
.img-wrap-quotes img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 70px;
 max-width: 226px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score -1):

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%; /*set width as you need it*/
    border: 3px solid #73AD21; /* just added border to check the alignment you can adjust*/
    padding: 10px;
    background:#ccc;  /* just added bg to check the alignment*/
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1c/LegalAndGeneral_Logo.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't matter with logo transparent/ non transparent. as a matter of fact you can't change the image/logo color.

Comment: Image is in outside the box.