# How to display images in elements with fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I have a lot of elements (`bootstrap` `html`) that behave responsive on a website. This means that they do not have a fixed width or height.

In each element an image should be displayed.

I tried to work with  `height` or `width`100% values. Also `min-height` or  `min-width` I have tried. I also tried it with a `div` and its `background-image`.

I also found this similar posts on Stackoverflow:

- [Wrap image in fixed height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405471/wrap-image-in-fixed-height-and-width)
- [Displaying images with adaptive width and fixed aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065723/displaying-images-with-adaptive-width-and-fixed-aspect-ratio)

Unfortunately, the first post based on fixed height and width. The second post is very helpful, but I search for a solution without using `JavaScript` (if this task is not solvable with pure `HTML` and `CSS`, I would try it with `JavaScript`).

I work with default bootstrap elements like this.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="element1" class="col-sm">
            <img id="img1" src="1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="element2" class="col-sm">
            <img id="img2" src="2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="element3" class="col-sm">
            <img id="img3" src="3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

All images should have the same width and height, although the image files have actually not the same width and height on file system.

If the images are too small or too large, the image should be scaled. If the ratio of height and width should not be correct, only a matching section of the image should be displayed.

Of course I do not expect finished solutions, but I would be very happy about approach ideas.

Comment: Is the <img/> tag required? Because you can use background-image on .col-sm elements, with background-size: cover; in that way the images will cover whole container, no matter the resolution of the image (while keeping the ratio of the image).

Comment: no, the img tag is not required. I tried it already with div elements and background-images. but i thought, that would not be a very efficient solution.

Comment: If you could provide a working demo of what you have that would be great. This would make things much easier to work with so maybe a code snippet in your question or maybe a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)